# Select Images from Mysql Explode

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

i have a database with images in the same row.
I can insert images with no problem, saves all, ok. But when in the main page i use the select from and try explode de commas, the first image its ok. But others don't.

Please check the image with what's happening and the code:
[Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6namO.png)

```
            <?php
session_start();

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "multiple"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_set_charset( $con, 'utf8');

        $query = "select file from student";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $images = $row['file'];
    $images = explode(',',$images);
    foreach($images AS $image){
        echo '<img src="uploads/'.$image.'">';
    }
    ?>
```

I don't have any spaces in file name, and just show's the first image. The others put the space betwen the folder and the filename.
Thank you

Comment: Any error messages you would like to share? Have you checked for error messages in the error logs?

Comment: What do you mean by "a normal sql form"? How is it different from the code you showed us, and what exactly is not working right now? There's also a lot of details in the PHP code that aren't relevant to the problem you're discussing, try to reduce it to a [mre]. In fact, I can't see any reference to the files or images in that PHP code at all, are you sure you've shown us the right query?

Comment: So where are you doing anything to do with the input field `files`. It does not look like you are do anything at all with the uploaded files. What exactly is your problem here

Comment: updated, really i have a missed code when i post here, but now its working ok. Just remains one more thing. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exploding by ',' but there seems extra space in your string. So, try like below (add a spase for first parameter):

```
$images = explode(', ',$images);
```

Comment: Yups, i forgot to check that in the mysql database.
Sorry for the noob question and thank you for your help.